# Springboot 1.5.7 / SpringDataJPA - Why methods in repository are not all transactional by default

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactional

This code in my repository :

```
public interface ClientRepository extends CrudRepository<Client, Long> {

//@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update Client c set c.firstName = ?1, c.lastName = ?2, c.email = ?3 where c.id = ?4")
void updateClientInfoById(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Long userId);
```

Executing this method(updateClientInfoById) using a REST Service give me this exception :  javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

I Have to add @Transactional to get it works.

why methods in repository are not all transactional by default ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only CRUD methods are by default marked as transactional. You are using custom query methods so you should explicitly mark it with `@Transactional` annotation.

> Additionally, we can get rid of the @Transactional annotation for the
>   method as the CRUD methods of the Spring Data JPA repository
>   implementation are already annotated with @Transactional.

For more informations, see [Getting started with Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa)

EDIT : CRUD methods are `CrudRepository` methods